# Reading the contents of a text file and assign to a variable using bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read the contents of a text file and check for the filenames with extension .txt and find merge those .txt files.Is there a way I could do this using bash?
For example, if the text file contains,
`file1.txt`, `file2.txt`
I want to read the strings with `.txt` extension and find merge those files which is in another location.

I tried the below,

```
txt_file="/tmp/Muzi/tomerge.txt"
while read -r line;do
    echo $line
done <"$txt_file"
```

But, this prints out the complete text file and I am completely new using `bash`.

Comment: It looks like this,

./MyProject/src/file1.java

./MyProject/src/file2.java
It is one file per line

Answer (score 1):

There is a good deal of assuming involved, but... if I understood your question, you would have a tomerge.txt where on some lines a filename would appear, one per line, ending in .txt. If that is the case (and the filenames do not contain spaces) you can:

```
cat $(grep '[.]txt$' tomerge.txt)
```

It's not bash only (uses cat), it concatenates files corresponding to all lines ending in `.txt` we've collected from `tomerge.txt`.